C++ STD template specialization inside another namespace
I've solved this problem which required me to group anagrams together.
So for the given input it should give the following output:
Input: strs = ["eat","tea","tan","ate","nat","bat"]
Output: [["bat"],["nat","tan"],["ate","eat","tea"]]
I decided to use a class called Signature to hold the character frequency for each word alongside a simple hashing algorithm
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <list>
#include <string>

template <class T> inline void hash_combine( std::size_t& seed, const T& v ) 
{
    std::hash<T> hasher;
    seed ^= hasher( v ) + 0x9e3779b9 + ( seed << 6 ) + ( seed >> 2 );
}

class Signature 
{
public:
    void Push( char c ) 
    {
        ++counts[c - 'a']; 
    }
    bool operator==( const Signature& rhs ) const 
    { 
        return counts == rhs.counts; 
    }
    size_t Hash() const 
    {
        size_t hash = 0;
        for( auto v : counts ) 
        {
            hash_combine( hash, v );
        }

        return hash;
    }

private:
    std::array<unsigned char, 26> counts = { 0 };
};

Then I use this template specialization:
namespace std 
{
    template <> struct std::hash<Signature> 
    {
        size_t operator()( const Signature& s ) const 
        { 
            return s.Hash(); 
        }
    };
}

Followed by this AnagramMap class which has an unordered map of the signatures
class AnagramMap 
{
public:
    void Push( const Signature& sig, int index ) 
    {
        auto val = map.emplace( sig, std::list{ index } );
        if( !val.second ) 
        {
            val.first->second.emplace_back( index );
        }
    }
    size_t GetSize() 
    { 
        return map.size(); 
    }
    auto begin() 
    { 
        return map.begin(); 
    }
    auto end() 
    { 
        return map.end(); 
    }

private:
    std::unordered_map<Signature, std::list<int>> map;
};

To finish this, the Solution class uses both the Signature and AnagramMap classes to solve the problem and return the anagrams properly grouped:
class Solution 
{
public:
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> groupAnagrams( std::vector<std::string>& strs )
    {
        AnagramMap anagrams;

        for( auto i = 0; i < strs.size(); ++i )
        {
            Signature sig;
            for( auto c : strs[i] )
            {
                sig.Push( c );
            }

            anagrams.Push( sig, i );
        }

        std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> result;

        for( auto& anagram : anagrams )
        {
            auto current_list = anagram.second;
            std::vector<std::string> current_anagram_group;

            while( !current_list.empty() )
            {
                auto current_anagram = strs[current_list.front()];
                current_list.pop_front();
                current_anagram_group.emplace_back( current_anagram );
            }
            result.emplace_back( current_anagram_group );
        }

        return result;
    }
};

This is all working fine, but now I wanted to move both the Signature and AnagramMap classes into a new namespace but not the Solution class, something like this:
namespace foo
{
    class Signature { ... }
    class AnagramMap { ... }
    
}

Is there a way to achieve this?

Explicit specialization may be declared in any scope where its primary template may be defined (which may be different from the scope where the primary template is defined; such as with out-of-class specialization of a member template). Explicit specialization has to appear after the non-specialized template declaration. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization

namespace std {    template <> struct std::hash<Signature> ... -- extra qualification is not allowed. You either specialize in enclosing namespace, i.e. global, writing struct std::hash... or in std namespace without qualifying hash

You should not specialize std::hash in the namespace std. You should specialize std::hash in the global namespace. When you use struct std::hash you already specialize it in the namespace std for a user defined type.
Since Signature is in the global namespace, the specialization should be
// DELETE namespace std 
// DELETE {
template <> struct std::hash<Signature> 
{
    size_t operator()( const Signature& s ) const 
    { 
        return s.Hash(); 
    }
};
// DELETE }

https://godbolt.org/z/v46G34GTq - compiles well in namespace foo.

Argument-dependent lookup has nothing to do with it. Specialization matching just considers all previous explicit and partial specialization declarations of that same primary template, no matter where those declarations were. Why do you say "you must not" specialize in namespace std?

what if Signature was inside the Foo namespace? I forgot to ask

It will work if you use Foo::Signature in the hash specialization.

OK, this question is closed but I might as well write this here. regarding your answer it solved the problem partially. The second part was that I had to break the namespace in 2.  First in the namespace I had to put the Signature class, then close the namespace, write the specialization in the global namespace and then open the namespace again and declare the AnagramMap class since now it knew how to hash the Signature object

This not a  discussion forum. Ask a new question with a [mre] instead of describing a code.
